# Pass multiple elements in onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables: `video` and `playPauseBtn`, It would be nice if the user could click on the either the button or the video, and have it trigger the `onclick` function. I want to use the variables instead of re-selecting the elements.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Video tag, playPauseBtn
        var video = $("#player").get(0),
            playPauseBtn = $(".playPauseBtn");


        //Play or pause
        playPauseBtn,video.on("click", function() {
            //If not playing ? Play  :  Puase 
            video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
            //Show play btn or Puase Btn
            playPauseBtn.toggleClass("playing");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playPauseBtn.add(video).on("click", function() {
```

Comment: You're welcome :)  I just made a small edit, because I noticed `playPauseButton` is already a jQuery object, so it doesn't need wrapping in `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The part where you define the click event for `playPauseBtn` and `video` isn't right. You aren't wrapping them in the jQuery function `$()`. To do that, you can pass an array to the jQuery function:

```
$([playPauseBtn.get(0),video]).on("click", function() {
```

Comment: i have test it now and click on video works.
Click on the btn does´t work